# how to allow only certain selected users to download data from site

Tags: php

I have a page in which i upload a circular & also select users who can view this page using multiple select dropdown box.
Now how to display the uploaded file to selected users when they login and not to other users.
Can anybody help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need to show MUCH more info...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always associate the users and the downloads in a DB table, and then, when the users log in you only show the associated downloads. Hope it helps, can't do much more with the info provided.